# Are questions about how law is made on topic?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/724/7) asks how a citizen can begin the process of changing the law.

Some questions about how law is made (and unmade) are clearly on topic; those concerning common law and precedent, for example. This one is more difficult because it's asking about the democratic process of effecting a change in the law, but part of me thinks that it too should be on topic, as questions about the validity of the resulting legislation will inevitably arise.

Should the example above be on topic and, if not, how do we draw the line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How law is made is a constitutional question, which seems very on-topic to me.

There are several recent US Supreme Court cases addressing how law was made. For example:

- Hollingsworth v. Perry
- Arizona State Legislature v. Arizona Independent Redistricting Commission

Comment: Not to mention the various cases (including the EPA case that came down today from SCOTUS) that describe how administrative law is made.

Comment: And *DOT v American Assoc. of Railroads*, Chevron deference, etc. etc.

Comment: Well yea the list is extensive. Just tying into current events

Comment: Gotcha. In any case, really seems that how law is made is on-topic.